# How to fix badly encoded JSON data for use in live google charts graph?

Tags: javascript, html, flask, google-api

I am using flask and google charts on a page on my website. I have a page that displays the last row of a database that is in a json object format as such:

```
{"temperature": 11.0, "datetime": "12-12-12 23-23-23"}
```

In flask I am making this getjson page as follows:

```
@app.route('/getjson')
def getjson():
    tempdata = getTemperatureData()
    return render_template('getjson.html', **locals())
```

This passes it the local variable tempdata. After this, I made a html file (getjson.html) with the simple code of:

```
{{tempdata}}
```

How ever when I load the webpage and check in the inspect element tab I get this which looks like pythonanywhere or flask has added all this html data as such:

```
<html>
    #shadow-root (open)
    <head></head>
    <body>{"temperature": 11.0, "datetime": "12-12-12 23-23-23"}</body>
</html>
```

My **problem** is that my google charts graph won't load and it seems to be receiving this data in the network preview tab in my browser, which looks completely modified from what I want it to receive (which it should be a json object) but it has all these added characters:

```
{&#34;temperature&#34;: 11.0, &#34;datetime&#34;: &#34;12-12-12 23-23-23&#34;}
```

The code for my google chart which should be able to live update is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Date Time');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Temperature');
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    var options = {
      title: 'Temperature Data',
      curveType: 'none',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    drawChart();
    setInterval(drawChart, 10000);

    function drawChart() {
      $.getJSON({
        url: 'removed from public view just in case',
        type: 'get'
      }).done(function (jsonData) {
        data.addRows([
          [jsonData.datetime, jsonData.temperature]
        ]);
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
      });
    }
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why does the JSON file you're getting have a .html extension, `getjson.html`? The `&#34;` characters you're seeing a double quotes, as they'd be rendered in an HTML file.

Comment: It's not a json file, I am receiving a json object printed in the HTML page, is this not the right way of doing it? I'm not too sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function decodeEntities(encodedString) {
  var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
  textArea.innerHTML = encodedString;
  return textArea.value;
}

function drawChart() {
  $.getJSON({
    url: 'removed from public view just in case',
    type: 'get'
  }).done(function (jsonData) {
    jsonData = decodeEntities(jsonData);
    data.addRows([
      [jsonData.datetime, jsonData.temperature]
    ]);
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. So do I put the decodeEntities function in my getjson.html page or literally above the drawchart function in the chart.html page

Comment: Where I showed it, above drawChart(), is a good place for it.

Comment: Oh, and don't forget to add `jsonData = decodeEntities(jsonData);` to drawChart().

Comment: I added your changes and still the error: parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 1
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at Nb (jquery.min.js:4)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: Is there a better way I can approach this solution? I'm really down to any suggestions as this problem has been going on for a while

Comment: I wasn't thinking about the fact that since you're using `getJSON` that it's too late after `getJSON` has been called to fix the bad encoding. You either need to change the source of your JSON so that it is real JSON, not HTML-encoded text, or use a jQuery `ajax` call instead, along with `decodeEntities` and `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Fixed, I used ajax call and decodeEntities function mentioned above. Thanks a lot.